# Unable to force Bootstrap button with alert class to show the alert text on its left side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

Hi all I have created two buttons in alligned in the two sides of my web page, one on the left and one the right side. Each button upon its click shows an alert text on its relevant side like in the picture [image]

The code that I have used is the following :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="previous">
       <button type="button" id="button_1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button1</button>
        <span  id="alert_info_1" class="alert alert-info">
                                 Alert Info
        </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
      <div class="next" >
        <button type="button" id="button_2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button2</button>
        <span id="alert_info_2" class="alert alert-info ">
                                Alert Info
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

While the css for the alignment of the buttons :

```
.previous {
text-align: left;
  }

.next {
 text-align: right;
  }
```

What I'd like to do is to make the alert info text of the button 2 to appear on the left side of the button and not on the right as it is show on the above picture

I've tried to add text-left in the button class but didn't work.
I also tried to add pull-left class in the span class, it forced the text to the left but the alert text appeared quite far from the button 2 as in the following image:
[image]

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: your code is working, first design you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace your second button and alert box then it will work and if you do not change your html , so need to add some extra css

```css
 .previous {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .next {
        text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="previous">
  <button type="button" id="button_1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button1</button>
  <span id="alert_info_1" class="alert alert-info">
                             Alert Info
    </span>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
<div class="next">
  <span id="alert_info_2" class="alert alert-info ">Alert Info</span>
  <button type="button" id="button_2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button2</button>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap second span and button:

```css
.previous {
  text-align: left;
}

.next {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="previous">
      <button type="button" id="button_1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button1</button>
      <span id="alert_info_1" class="alert alert-info">
                                 Alert Info
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
    <div class="next">
      <span id="alert_info_2" class="alert alert-info ">Alert Info</span>
      <button type="button" id="button_2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```